# what does "positive statement" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, nouns

One of the definitions for "affirmation" in the American Heritage Dictionary is:

2. Something declared to be true; **a positive statement** or judgment.

I know that one of the synonyms for "affirm" is "confirm"

**confirm, prove, sanction, endorse, ratify, verify, validate, bear out, substantiate, corroborate,** ***authenticate** Everything I had accomplished seemed to affirm that opinion.*(collins dictionary)

"Something declared to be true" from the definition **seems like a "confirmation"**
Is "positive statement" also a confirmation?

One of the synonyms I found for "positive" is:

**"affirmative"**

2. Giving assent or approval; confirming: *an affirmative vote*.(American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language)

Is a "positive statement" the same as an "affirmative statement"/"confirming statement"?

Comment: Negative statements are most useful for confusing people and weaseling the truth. E.g. "*I didn't tell Fred he was an idiot*" is true, while a positive form of that truth is "*I told Joe that Fred was an idiot, and Fred happened to overhear me.*".  Or, compare "*I don't think you're stupid.*" with "*I know you're stupid.*". Both statements can be true, but the negative statement is misleading.

Comment: Without a context, "positive statement" doesn't have any clear meaning. It can mean a statement that is positive in all meanings that "positive" has. In some contexts, it could have the same meaning as "affirmative statement", or as "confirming statement", but these three phrases are not equivalent. So please update your question to include the context.

Answer (score 1):

In grammar, a positive statement is one which states something that the speaker believes to be a fact, e.g. "I own two cars", "I went to the beach yesterday", "I am going to France on holiday". In contrast, a negative statement proposes that something is not the case, and normally uses "not", "no", or the clitic "n't" (possibly with other words like "any"), e.g. "I don't own two cars", "I did not go to the beach", "I don't have any holiday plans"... (The actual truth of the statement doesn't affect whether it is positive or negative, it's purely a grammatical category based on sentence structure.)

This can be found in many websites and books discussing grammar, e.g. [Your Dictionary](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/positive-sentence-examples.html), [EnglishBix](https://www.englishbix.com/positive-and-negative-sentences-examples/).

Comment: In grammar, we'd say a *declarative utterance or sentence*, as opposed to negative, interrogative or negative interrogative.

Answer (score 0):

The sense 2 of "affirmation" is a type of statement. In rhetoric, when you state that something is true, that is an affirmation.

> Most cats have four legs.

Is a statement, and a positive statement.

> It is true that most cats have four legs.

Is an affirmation.

...

And to affirm something is similar in meaning to "confirm".  Because to confirm is to establish the truth of something that was in doubt.  It's different but close in meaning to "affirm".

So if you were unsure about the number of legs that cats had (but thought it might be four) you could try to confirm this fact by scientific investigation of cat legs.

Having confirmed the truth of the positive statement "most cats have four legs", you would be in a position to state it, and even to affirm it, if you were challenged on its truth.

Comment: @gotube The context, in this case, is the definition from the American Heritage dictionary. You can't figure out which sense of the word it is by reading a definition in a dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary definitions are short and useful but can't capture every aspect of use.  For example,  "Cats *do* have four legs." may be considered to be an affirmation of the fact, even though grammatically it is equivalent to the simple statement. Affirmations positively assert the truth of some fact or the existence of some entity, rather than neutrally stating it.  It is a category in rhetoric, not grammar.

Comment: This whole "affirmation" seems to me like a simple "confirmation" and "positive" like "affirmative" and thefreedictionary seems to agree with me listing "affirmative" as a synonym for "positive" and "confirm" as a synonym for "affirm". Even though I read all of your guy's answers I'm non the wiser as to what these things mean so I will stick with that =P But thanks anyway:)))

Comment: Okay, short version "confirmation" and "affirmation" are have some senses that are similar and some senses that are different.  Synonym means "word with similar meaning", not "word with same meaning".